# How to delete existing migrations in Django 1.7

Tags: python, django

So i'm following the Tango with Django guide, specifically part [7.3.2.](http://www.tangowithdjango.com/book17/chapters/models_templates.html) of the tutorial. After I ran the command `python3 manage.py makemigrations rango`, it won't let me re-populate the database using the `populate` script. Instead I got the error: `django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such column: rango_category.slug`.

Then, I tried to revert things back to normal by deleting all the `slug` code (so before 7.3 of the guide). I made a migration after doing so, but then because the prior migration which added the slug category was never deleted, I can't use the `migrate` command to revert my changes because it throws an error when it tries to `migrate` using the old `Added category slug` migration. Even when I specifically point to the newest migration, it still gives me an error for the old one.

Then, in an effort to fix things, I used a bunch of different `migrate` and `makemigrations` commands, including `--empty, --fake, squashmigrations` etc and now my migrations look unrecognizable. **Is there a way to just delete all these existing migrations and just start from a completely clean slate?**

This is what `migrate --list` looks like now, for reference:

`admin
 [ ] 0001_initial
auth
 [ ] 0001_initial
rango
 [ ] 0001_squashed_0003_category_slug (3 squashed migrations)
 [ ] 0001_squashed_0005_auto_20150328_0917 (5 squashed migrations)
contenttypes
 [ ] 0001_initial
sessions
 [ ] 0001_initial`

Comment: Delete the `migrations` folder inside `rango`.Also delete database which created.Then restart your migration process

Comment: oh wow thank you very much @itzmeontv! it was as easy as that

Answer (score 1):

For a clean start.

- Delete the `migrations` folder inside `rango`
- delete database which created.Then restart your migration process

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to delete the migrations folder, only the migrations files, but leave __init__.py there.